# Junit5 @MethodSource passing parameter to the method

Tags: junit5

I'm looking for how to pass a parameter into a metod that use the @MethodSource annotatio in Junit5

For example I need to invoke @MethodSource annotation and passing a value into the method "MyFactoryMethod".  It is possible?
Sometings like this:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("MyFactoryMethod(10)")
void testWithMethodSource(int argument) {
    assertNotEquals(9, argument);
}

static IntStream MyFactoryMethod(String var) {
    return IntStream.range(0, var);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, it's not supported, at least in Jupiter JUnit v.5.8.2.

You are allowed to provide names of methods within the test class as well as external classes.
Note that methods in external classes must be referenced by fully qualified method name - *com.package.Class#**methodName***.

Example:

Referring to a method within the test class
`@MethodSource("getParams")`

External methods
`@MethodSource("com.app.test.ArgumentsProvider#getArgs")`

There is an option to implement a custom annotation of your own, if nothing else suits you maybe consider that.

[Example of how to implement such annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5#8-custom-annotation)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple workaround, just use method override:

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("myFactoryMethod10")
void testWithMethodSource(int argument) {
    assertNotEquals(10, argument);
}

@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("myFactoryMethod9")
void testWithMethodSource(int argument) {
    assertNotEquals(9, argument);
}

public static IntStream myFactoryMethod10() {
   return factoryMethod(10);
}

public static IntStream myFactoryMethod9() {
   return factoryMethod(9);
}

static IntStream factoryMethod(String var) {
    return IntStream.range(0, var);
}
```

You can then create versions of `myFactoryMethod` as required for individual tests. An extra step, but workable - huh?

The above solution may appear as an overkill for the above simple case, but imagine your `factoryMethod` is complex and creating many parameters, then the above method pays off.